# Automation for baked rigid body dynamics baking, creating armatures, and transferring to armatures

Tags: animation, scripting, armature, bones, rigid-body-simulation

[image: Rigid body simulation]
I would like to streamline the process of creating game ready baked rigid body simulations, and I am wondering if there already exists function, add-on, or script which does this. This would expand the possibility of having more complex effects (more dynamic bodies baked).

Specifically the purpose of whatever function, add-on, and script would be to create an armature at rest position, where there is a bone for every object in the scene, each of the bones' head is at the center of each object, and the tail is always pointing +Z. Afterwards a copy location and rotation constraint would be applied to each bone and linked to the appropriate object, afterwards, each object would be weighed under the vertex weight for the appropriate bone.

I'm not trying to request that someone create, although I'm sure others would appreciate it for creating their own simulations.

In terms of manually creating these simulations, it is a tedious process.
For reference, see this video in which a simulation is created for The Dark Mod:

[Blender - bake physics to armature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ppe7R6kmNGU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blendermarket.com/products/ossim
This tool provides almost exactly what I am looking for.